# Vimeo video not playing in firefox

Tags: firefox, video-streaming

Videos on vimeo don't play in firefox (nor embedded, nor directly on vimeo site).

They load. I can see and move the player to see different pictures but the player does not start.

Firefox 46 / Ubuntu 14.04

Video plays when using a new profile and no add-ons.

Comment: Do they work in chrome?

Comment: No, Vimeo videos do not play in Google Chrome as of Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 4):

I circumvented the problem by changing the setting

**media.autoplay.enabled** to true

(in url: *about:config*)

Comment: FYI, the Firefox bug about this: [media.autoplay.enabled set to false is breaking user experience (videos won't play)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1231886).